# Returning To Main Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, return

My application has three activities. The *main* activity, a *play game* activity, and a *game over* activity. The main activity starts the play game activity after a button is pressed:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), PlayGameActivity.class);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

Inside the play game activity, when the game is over, I start the game over activity the same way:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), GameOver.class);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

Inside the *game over* activity when the user clicks the hardware *back* button I want it to return to the main activity (not the play game activitiy which is what's currently happening).

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(GameActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
             startActivity(intent);
           // finish(); // un-comment <--- this to close the previous activity if you don't want to use it anymore.
}
```

this will handle the back button. just add it in your game activity class. 
please do accept the answer if its what you seek for.

Comment: Do you mean put this in my game over activity?

Comment: yes. put it over there. change change the GameActivity with the name of the current class and the MainActivity to your main class.

Comment: yes put it in your game over activity and this will overwrite the default behavior of back button.

Comment: This is not a very correct approach because you are creating a new instance of an activity that is already in the stack

Comment: Mr.Me is correct here. Consider your activities as a stack you are traveling through. Besides the correct answer from Hoan Nguyen, you can use in your code as well Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY

Comment: yeah he is correct thats y he used the same as mine below @VincentNikkelen

Comment: @StyleMe I meant the android:noHistory option. By the way, none of the provided solutions will work when we extend the original question to 4 activities, where one can travel through the first 3 but from the 4th only can go to the 1st without creating a new instance on the stack. Any ideas?

Comment: @Vincent Nikkelen The answer is yes for API 16 or later. Use taskAffinity and called finishAffinity on onBackPressed in activity 4

Answer (score 2):

On your Manifest add

```
android:noHistory="true"
```

to your PlayGameActivity

Answer (score -1):

As @Hoan Nguyen stated. you can add `android:noHistory="true"` to your gameactivity in the **AndroidManifest.xml** file.

or you could finish your game activity once you started the **GameOver** Activity. and the code should look something like this:

```
///on Game Over
Intent intent = new Intent(GameActivity.this, GameOverActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Those ways you will get back to the original instance of your **MainAcitivty** instead of lunching a new one.